# CSS - Fluid before / after icon method for bottom border

Tags: css

I'm struggling to achieve this effect -

[image]

Basically the line below needs to be fluid - I cant get my head around how to do this with a bottom border - any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: Add a new jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a pure css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lkxfqe/

You can drag the left separation bar to the right to see it's responsive and gets smaller as you decrease the screen width.

As you see it's effect is very easy to achieve with the pseudo elements 'before' and 'after'.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/150x100") center center no-repeat;
}

.container:before{
    z-index: 1; 
    position: absolute; 
    content: " "; 
    bottom: -6px; 
    left: -5px; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    background: #CCC;
}

.container:after{
    z-index: 1; 
    position: absolute; 
    content: " "; 
    bottom: -6px; 
    right: -5px; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```